# R - getting box plot to work

Tags: r, boxplot

```
boxplot(data=max_urkoma[[2]])
```

I have a data set `max_urkoma[[2]]` that I'd like to put into a box plot, but it won't show at all unless I give it the formula `max_urkoma[[1]]~max_urkoma[[2]]`, and then it'll basically just become a set of points on a plot. What am I doing wrong? The plot is acting like every item in the data set is a separate object, I want them grouped together like in this one:

http://onlinestatbook.com/2/graphing_distributions/graphics/figure4.jpg

THis is how mine looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJJNy.jpg

Comment: You haven't provided a sample of your data, but here's an example of a boxplot using the built-in `mtcars` dataset: `boxplot(mpg ~ carb, data=mtcars)`. This code gives a separate boxplot of `mpg` for each level of `carb`.

Comment: What if all I want is one boxplot? How do I get one with one data set I have?

Comment: `boxplot(mtcars$mpg)`. With your data, it looks like you want `boxplot(max_urkoma[[2]])`. If you post a small sample of your data, it will be easier to provide help.

Comment: That was it! Thank you! Strange that the most obvious forms of the boxplot eluded me. I'll mark your answer if you post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a single boxplot, you can do `boxplot(mtcars$mpg)`, or with your data it looks like you need `boxplot(max_urkoma[[2]])`.